# Change date format in a txt/csv file with , separator

Tags: c#, csv, datetime

I have a lot of `.txt` files with data in it. The data is separated with a `,`.

In the third column the data is in the `dd-mm-yyyy` format. But it has to be in `yyyy/mm/dd` format. Changing the machine format isn't a solution.

The files are small enough to load into memory and opened on the following way, but I can't figured out how to solve the date issue. Who can help me?

```
        foreach (string x in a)
        {
            string somePath = @"C:\test\";
            string filename = x;
            string path = Path.Combine(somePath, filename);

            string str = File.ReadAllText(path);
            str = str.Replace("AS", "");
            File.WriteAllText(path, str);
        }
```

Comment: Read a line, split line by `,`, get the date string, parse it and replace with the correct format, write the line, repeat until finished?

Comment: [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can also take a look at [TextFieldParser Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) for parsing CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example using `ReadAllLines()` and `WriteAllLines()`:

```
        string[] lines;
        string somePath = @"C:\test\";
        foreach (string x in a)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(somePath, x);
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length;i++)
            {
                lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("AS", "");

                string[] values = lines[i].Split(',');
                if (values.Length >= 3)
                {
                    string[] parts = values[2].Split('-');
                    if (parts.Length == 3)
                    {
                        values[2] = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", parts[2], parts[1], parts[0]);
                        lines[i] = String.Join(",", values);
                    }
                }
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't address OP's requirement to change the date format.

Comment: @Tim...?...sure it does.  It takes column three and splits it on dash, then puts it back together in the desired order with "/".  Afterwards it puts the line back together and updates the "lines" array.  Finally the entire array is written back out...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  But why not use `DateTime.TryParseExact`?

Comment: Simply because there was already an example of it being used.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through all the lines, split the string, try to parse it, then write it in the correct format to the output file.

```
foreach (string x in a)
{

    string somePath = @"C:\test\";
    string filename = x;
    string path = Path.Combine(somePath, filename);

    string str = File.ReadAllText(path);
    str = str.Replace("AS", "");
    var lines = str.Split('\n');
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        var parts = line.Split(',');
        if(parts.Length > 2)
        {
            var d = parts[2];
            DateTime dateValue;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(d, "dd-MM-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                 DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
                {
                    var dateTxt = dateValue.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd");
                      ...etc...

                 }
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(path, str);
    }
```

Comment: How are you going to put `dateTxt` back into the correct position in `str` when you use `WriteAllText()`?...

Comment: This isn't a complete solution, it is meant to perhaps be helpful as you write the rest.